# Selenium, python - Как найти элемент и получить его атрибуты у инстаграма?

Tags: selenium

Пишу бота для инстаграма. В данный момент столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу найти элемент и получить его атрибуты.

Вкратце опиши алгоритм: функция получает на вход список аккаунтов --> **в цикле:** заходит на страницу аккаунта --> нажимает на поле, где показываются с подписчиками --> вылазит окошко, с которого она берет имена аккаунтов (см. фото) --> записывает в базу данных и идет дальше.

Сама проблема заключается в том, что у инстаграма динамические классы (не знаю точное название), из-за этого четко прописать элемент через `xpath` не получается. Если мы пробуем найти все ссылки на странице и убрать лишнее:

```
a = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
hrefs = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in a]
hrefs = hrefs[:num_hashs]
```

То получим, что Selenium ищет ссылки только на странице пользователя, игнорируя окно.

Как быть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Когда вы нажали на открытие окна, ваше DOM дерево изменилось, подгрузился дополнительный блок, который отвечает за это окно.
Окно можно найти по атрибуту role в значении presentation. Вот в нем и ищите. Ну а если по теме, то разве нет библиотек для работы в Instagram? Selenium очень медленный и не стабильный вариант парсинга.

Comment: @danilshik, спасибо! Как можно искать ссылки в выбранном DOM узле? Какие библиотеки посоветуете для проекта?

Comment: ну сначала попробуйте найти корневой элемент: root = driver.find_element...... А потом a = root.find_element_by_class_name('a')